# Python 3 - One-Line Polymorphic String Formatting

Tags: python, string-formatting

Is there any way to have a single `str.format()` or `Template().substitute()` expression that is polymorphic? Example:

```python
datetime_object = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
'{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(datetime_object)  # -> '2015-09-19'

datetime_object = None
'{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(datetime_object)  # raises TypeError() from NoneType.__format__()
                                       # Ideally -> 'None'
```

Does any current notation support a single in-line expression that doesn't require manually specifying different format strings based on the type of the arg(s)? A notation like:

```python
'{:%Y-%m-%d?NoneType!r}'.format(...)
```

Obviously, I can do so manually:

```python
('{:%Y-%m-%d}' if date_object else '{!r}').format(date_object)
```

This approach leads to combinatorial explosion on format string creation with multiple args.

An all-in-one would be nice (within reason; format strings can already get hairy).

Comment: Not sure there is a one size fits all but using a function to create your formatting could at least make it a bit more managable

Comment: Yeah. It occurs to me the problem with my notation is scoping - what does NoneType mean in the scope of the function call? Built-in types are obvious, but what about custom? Would names have to be fully qualified?

Comment: None does not have a `__format__` method so the only thing that would would work would be `"{}".format(None)` or `!r`as you have used